# Refreshing current browser within iframe

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iframe

I created a Registration Page in MVC 7 for a company but they only implemented the page as an iframe so once the user is successfully registered I redirect my created page to their home page but because this was implemented as an iframe, only the iframe loads the homepage so it looks like the website is inside itself. My page is also hosted on a different service as the website they implemented the iframe on. I do not have access to the current website's back-end so I was wondering if there was a way to refresh the entire website and not just the iframe. If anybody has some advise on how to do this using any method allowed on MVC I would appreciate that.

Comment: Not entirely certain this will work for MVC but <form target="_top">

Comment: @Kevin Will try that as well on my solution. Thanks